# Wrap the contents of an element in a ".content" div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap the contents of a form `element` in a div with the class `.content` and I'm getting an error that the inner `$(element).html()` is a "unrecognized expression".

```
$(element).html($($(element).html()).wrap($("<div>").addClass(".content")));
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$(element).wrapInner('<div class="content" />')
```